# is it possible to change the app name and icon programmatically from a class during its first execution?

Tags: android

```
public class SettingsPage extends Activity{
    EditText edname,ednumber;
    Sharedprefference shpreff;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settingspage);
        shpreff = new Sharedprefference(getApplicationContext());
        edname=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editname);
        ednumber=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editnumbr);

        lname=edname.getText().toString();
        lnumber=ednumber.getText().toString();
        shpreff.setName(lname);
        shpreff.setPhonenumber(lnumber);
        shpreff.setCheck("true");
        shpreff.setChStat("true");
    }
```

this code is used to store the name and number from a login page to sharedprefference.
here edname is the text which reads from editext.
I want to change the app name as the name which gets in  edname after store it in sharedprefference and want to change icon according to users input.

Comment: with app name and icon you're referring to change the app name and icon defined in the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

1 . Modify your `MainActivity` section in `AndroidManifest.xml`, delete the line I mention you in the code in intent-filter section

```
<activity android:name="ru.quickmessage.pa.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        ==> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <== Delete this line
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />//DELETE THIS LINE
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

2 . Create an `<activity-alias>`, for each of your icons. Like this:

```
<activity-alias android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:name=".MainActivity-Red"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>   
</activity-alias>
```

3 . Set the `ComponentEnabledSetting` attribute for the appropriate `activity-alias`:

```
 getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
        new ComponentName("ru.quickmessage.pa", "ru.quickmessage.pa.MainActivity-Red"), 
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: @andreu-rodradguez-i-donaire , i want to set the picture which upload by the user as app icon after its first execution . so how i can use <activity_alias>..? .during the programming time how we cant predict the alternate pic?

Comment: set the icon in `<activity-alias>` as the name you want, and then save the uploaded image with this name like a resource drawable. Then enable the alias

Comment: @ andreu-rodradguez-i-donaire, i heard that if we change the app name after its execution (using <activity-alias>) the app may be collapsed.. isn't it ?

Comment: I think that if you use the flag `PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP` as I said in my answer it wouldn't crash.

Comment: @ andreu-rodradguez-i-donaire, OK then i want to one more thing.. if i install this app in mob with a name and pic, can i install the same app with different name and pic in the same phone ?.(any problems due to same package name)